# Create multi-level ellipses with PIL

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library

I am looking to create multi level ellipses with PIL. The idea, is it has to be a completely white (255) at the center ellipse, and as it grows outwards, there should be a gradient, and slowly become black (0)

For some reason, it is not creating the white pixels, at the center. I verified by using `getpixel` function

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

width = 1200
height = 1200
img = Image.new("L", (width, height)) # 1200pixels imitating 1 X 1 feet

max_width = 600#imitating 6 inches
max_height = 150# imitating 1.5 inches

eX, eY = max_width, max_height
for i in range(256):
    bbox = (width/2 - eX/2, height/2 - eY/2, width/2 + eX/2, height/2 + eY/2)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.ellipse(bbox, fill=i)
    eX = eX - 1
    eY = eY - 1
img.save("new.png")
print (img.getpixel(xy=(600,600)))
```

When I print the value I should get - 255, but the output is 148.

https://ibb.co/51cggfj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're always reducing your `eY` variable by `1` on each iteration, you reach a height of zero before you finish the loop. An ellipse with no height doesn't draw, so you're only seeing the last positive height as a narrow line of the brightest color (which isn't white).

To fix the issue, you probably need to scale your dimensions some other way. For instance, you could replace all the `eX` and `eY` computations with this, at the top of the loop:

```
# no need to initialize eX and eY before the loop
for i in range(256):
    eX, eY = max_width * 256 / (256-i), max_height * 256 / (256-i)  # compute scaled values
    bbox = (width/2 - eX/2, height/2 - eY/2, width/2 + eX/2, height/2 + eY/2)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.ellipse(bbox, fill=i)
    # no longer subtract from eX and eY down here
```

This is a different kind of scaling than you were doing before, you could stick with something more like what you were doing before if you want, you'd just need to adjust the logic to only get to `eY` of 1 right at the end.